# Deploying Solution to Remote SharePoint Site

Tags: 2010, solution-deployment

I have a SP2010 wsp. I want to deploy it to some remote SharePoint site. I don't have access to root site on the remote server but to a sub site, where I want my solution. How can I directly deploy my solution to the sub site?

Same is the case with some SSRS reports and its data source. I want these to be deployed to the same sub site.

Please suggest.

Comment: is your solution sandboxed?

Comment: not its not sandboxed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Site Action->Site Settings
2. Galleries -> Solutions
3. Solutions Tab-> Upload Solution

Then you should activate your solutions.

Good luck!

Comment: seems like I don't have access to activate the solution.

Answer (score 4):

None-sandboxed solutions must be deployed by Farm Administrators. You will need to package the solution and send it to the relevant people who can deploy it via STSADM or PowerShell as taste dictates.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have access to the Site Collection to be able to upload Sandboxed Solutions. If you don't have access to the Site Collection admin stuff, then you need to contact the Site Collection Owners.